# Как через код можно управлять системой частиц?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как через код можно управлять системой частиц?

У меня есть автомобиль и из его выхлопной трубы идет дым. Размер (длина) этого дыма меняется в зависимости от скорости автомобиля. Т.е. игрок набирает высокую скорость — длина дыма увеличивается, игрок уменьшает скорость — длина дыма уменьшается. Изначально скорость автомобиля постоянно уменьшается до тех пор, пока он не подберет буст на увеличение скорости. Как сделать плавное изменение размера дыма от скорости автомобиля?

Пробовал делать так:

```
public class speedParticle : MonoBehaviour {
    private SpeedManager SpeedManager;
    private ParticleSystem thisParticeSystem;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        thisParticeSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        SpeedManager = FindObjectOfType<SpeedManager>();

    }
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

       thisParticeSystem.startLifetime = SpeedManager.Speed;
    }
}
```

Но это не работает.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: а что значит "не работает"? дым всегда одной длины? или дыма вообще нет? Я бы сначала вывел в лог SpeedManager.Speed, чтобы убедиться, что оно изменяется так, как тебе надо... ну и заодно увидел бы реальные значения, и скорее всего, захотел бы ввести какой-то коэффициент (SpeedManager.Speed * SpeedToLengthFactor), который потом подгонял бы в инспекторе до достижения желаемого эффекта.

Comment: @AlexandrX дым всегда одной длинны. Смотрел через инспектор, значение startLifetime изменяется, но длинна дыма остается прежней

Comment: меняются в достаточном диапазоне? если руками в тех же пределах менять - эффект есть?

Comment: А вы уверены, что `startLifetime` относится к системе частиц?? по моему это параметр частиц [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Particle-startLifetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема может быть решена проще. Поменяйте у ParticleSystem в редакторе свойство simulation space  с Local на World. Тогда генерируемый дым будет оставаться в игровом мире, а не менять свое положение вслед за автомобилем, как будто он к нему крепится. [image: здесь этот параметр]